# How do I add items to a gtk.ComboBox created through glade at runtime?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm using Glade 3 to create a GtkBuilder file for a PyGTK app I'm working on. It's for managing bandwidth, so I have a gtk.ComboBox for selecting the network interface to track.

How do I add strings to the ComboBox at runtime? This is what I have so far:

```
self.tracked_interface = builder.get_object("tracked_interface")

self.iface_list_store = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
self.iface_list_store.append(["hello, "])
self.iface_list_store.append(["world."])
self.tracked_interface.set_model(self.iface_list_store)
self.tracked_interface.set_active(0)
```

But the ComboBox remains empty. I tried RTFM'ing, but just came away more confused, if anything.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could just create and insert the combo box yourself using [`gtk.combo_box_new_text()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html#function-gtk--combo-box-new-text). Then you'll be able to use gtk shortcuts to [append](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--append-text), [insert](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--insert-text), [prepend](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--prepend-text) and [remove](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcombobox.html#method-gtkcombobox--remove-text) text.

```
combo = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
combo.append_text('hello')
combo.append_text('world')
combo.set_active(0)

box = builder.get_object('some-box')
box.pack_start(combo, False, False)
```

Answer (score 6):

Hey, I actually get to answer my own question!

You have to add gtk.CellRendererText into there for it to actually render:

```
self.iface_list_store = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
self.iface_list_store.append(["hello, "])
self.iface_list_store.append(["world."])
self.tracked_interface.set_model(self.iface_list_store)
self.tracked_interface.set_active(0)
# And here's the new stuff:
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.tracked_interface.pack_start(cell, True)
self.tracked_interface.add_attribute(cell, "text", 0)
```

Retrieved from, of course, the [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq16.008.htp).

*Corrected example thanks to Joe McBride*

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the last parameter of `add_attribute` is the column from the ListStore that you want to display. In your case `0` is the right choice, but I needed `1` because I wanted to display the string from a `Gtk.ListStore(int, str)`.